# Issue regarding the Order of Inner Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, inner-join

Consider one table `tbl1` with `ID` and `Name`.
A table-valued parameter `params` with `ID`.

I need to duplicate the rows in `tbl1` which have the `ID` contained in `params`.
I am trying to insert like this

```
insert into tbl1(Name,somevalues..) 
   select tbl1.Name, tbl1.somevalues..
   from @params p 
   inner join tbl1 on tbl1.ID=p.ID  -- here ID is identity (PK).
```

But after insertion, it is found that the order of insertion is different. If I am running the select query alone, it will display the ID based on `@params` (TVP). But the same query when I used after insert will perform in a different way.

order in TVP / Select Query - A
order when insert using Select Query - B

```
 A       B 
370294  370294
368702  368702
369157  368504
368914  368505
368505  368914
368504  369157
368508  368506
368506  368507
368507  368508
368912  368637
368637  368638
368638  368639
368639  368912
368915  368915
368641  368641
```

There some ID's which are different in order.

What will be the issue for different order?

How can I insert values in the same order as in my TVP ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A DBMS has **no** concept of ordering unless you use an **explicit** `ORDER BY`. In your case, using SQL Server, adding a Clustered Index on your table will physically guarantee an order on that field(s).

Comment: A SQL Server table has **no implicit** order - you only get something ordered if you **explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @marc_s  But when in select query alone it will return results in the order in the TVP. So how this will possible ?

Comment: @Harie: if you have no `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` - there is **NO GUARANTEE** for any ordering. If you need order - specify it - that's the **ONLY** way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always: ORDER is arbitrary without an ORDER BY.

This means that even if you did use ORDER BY for the INSERT, then a later SELECT isn't guaranteed to return with this order **unless** you use ORDER BY on the SELECT.

In other words: there is no *implied* or *natural* order to a table or view. 

You can only have a defined order with ORDER BY

Edit

However. it should be noted that INNER JOINs are both commutative and associative. That is, you get the *same* results. You're asking about ORDER which I answered above

For more, see

- [How order of joins affect performance of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7820005/27535)
- [how to best organize the Inner Joins in (select) statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899715/27535)

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on the order of insertion on your `SELECT` queries. Use the `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the `SELECT` to define how to order the results.